# How to put the first date of this year in a WHERE clause. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

I need my query to select all dates between the first date of this year and the present date. (ie all dates in database within this year), however my code does this but for the last 12 months. How can i alter my code to ensure its only dates from this year?

```
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= date
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ...
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= date AND
      YEAR(your_datecolumn) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: Is the DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= date not needed now?

Comment: you have mentioned that your query did but for the last 12 months, so by adding `AND
      YEAR(your_datecolumn) = YEAR(CURDATE())` will filter the record by current year only. by the way, did you test the query?

Answer (score 1):

```
where created_date between MAKEDATE(YEAR(now()), 1) and now();
```

MAKEDATE(YEAR(now()), 1) gives you '01/01/(thisyear)'